# Unable to generate Extent Report in Selenium Java

Tags: java, extentreports

I am trying to generate Extent Report in selenium. I have written the exact code for generating report , but the folder in which the report must be saved is empty, I have refreshed the project as well but still not able to produce report.Please let me know if I have done any thing wrong in the coding part. Here is my code:

```
public class ContactUsTestCase {

    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    ExtentReports extent;
    ExtentTest test;

    static WebDriver driver;
    UtilityMethods util = new UtilityMethods();

    @BeforeClass
    public void launchBrowser() {
        driver = UtilityMethods.openBrowser(Constants.BROWSER_NAME);
        UtilityMethods.launchWebsite(Constants.URL);

    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void startReport() {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\ExtentReport");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "win 10");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "Stewart");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Chrome");
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation testig report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Your Logo Report Name");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void ContactUs() {

        test = extent.createTest("ContactUs", "This wil check status for Conatct us page");

        // util.clickElement(Constants.OPEN_CONTACTUS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("stewart****@yahoo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("******");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")).click();

        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("PASS", ExtentColor.GREEN));

    }

    @AfterClass

    public void teardown() {

        extent.flush();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned the folder name alone. Change this line

```
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\ExtentReport");
```

in your code to

```
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("D:\\ExtentReport\\nameOfTheReport.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed extension for html report, 
Your path should be `"D:\\Demo_ExtentReport.html"`